# OnClick for Drawer in relative layout doesnt work

Tags: android, android-listview, slidingdrawer, drawerlayout

I have a layout which has drawer in it 
There are 3 tabs in tab 3 I need to put a layout looking similar to this !
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSz7o.jpg)

Now when I try to click on any item in drawer the `onclick` doesn't work

**My XML code**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@color/blue_end_grdeient"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"  >

<!-- The main content view -->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" />
<!-- The navigation drawer -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/blue_end_grdeient"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:background="@color/blue_end_grdeient"

        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/grey"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" 
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"/>
</LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/helpview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible" 
    android:background="#80000000"
    android:alpha="0.9">




    <Button
        android:id="@+id/invisible_button"
        style="@color/blue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Ok! Got it !"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />



        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/dummy"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/fab_button_diameter"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/fab_button_diameter"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_button_margin_bottom"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_button_margin_right"
            android:background="@drawable/fab_shape"
            android:src="@drawable/fab_ic_add"
            android:tint="@android:color/white"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:clickable="false"

             />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/downButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/dummy"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/dummy"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow1_bottom" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/addMemberTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/downButton"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Click here to Add New Members"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/next1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/dummy"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
             android:background="@color/new_orange"
             android:paddingLeft="10dp"
             android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="Ok, Got it!" 
            android:focusable="false"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ic_dots_vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:visibility="invisible"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_dots_vertical" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/syncTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/arrow_top"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:text="Click here to SYNC data with server"

            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />



        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/arrow_top"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ic_dots_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow1_top" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**My code for showing this Image**

```
public void OnActionBarChanged(String mType) {

    if(mType.equals("2"))
    {
        setActionBarMembers();
        shared_preference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String mFirstTiem = shared_preference.getString("FIRST_TIME_HELP",
                "null");
        if (mFirstTiem.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
            helpview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    helpview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared_preference.edit();
                    editor.putString("FIRST_TIME_HELP", "DONE");
                    editor.commit();
                }
            });
        }


    }
    else
    {
        setActionBar();
        helpview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

The code for Drawer List is

```
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}
public void selectItem(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments

    // Bundle args = new Bundle();
    // args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
    // fragment.setArguments(args);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (position == 0) {

        Intent mStart = new Intent(this, ProfileView.class);
        startActivity(mStart);

    } else if (position == 1) {

        Intent mStart = new Intent(this, SettingsView.class);
        startActivity(mStart);
    }

    else if (position == 2) {
        // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Work In Progress",
        // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent mStart = new Intent(this, HowToUseActivity.class);
        mStart.putExtra("type", "Help");

        startActivity(mStart);
    }
     else if (position == 3) {
            Intent mProcess = new Intent(this, MemberShipProcess.class);
            startActivity(mProcess);
        }

    else if (position == 4) {
        Intent mStart = new Intent(this, HowToUseActivity.class);
        mStart.putExtra("type", "FAQ");
        startActivity(mStart);
    }

    else if (position == 5) {
        Intent mStart = new Intent(this, NeedHelp.class);
        startActivity(mStart);
    }

    else if (position == 6) {
        Intent mStart = new Intent(this, AboutThisApp.class);
        startActivity(mStart);
    }

    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
```

Comment: Where is `listView.setOnItemClickListener()` method??? The code you have provided  showing `next.setOnClickListener()`  which is a `button` or `listview` or any other view???

Comment: and next is a 'button' with relation to id next1 in the XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried making the ListView and its parent layout ("drawer") clickable?

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Comment: in my case the parent layout would be??

Comment: the linear layout above the listView ("drawer") - i edited my answer, you could also try to set the ListVIew itself clickable

Comment: are you setting the ItemClickListener on the ListView correctly?  -  since it is not visible in the code

Comment: ' mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener()); '

Comment: seems fine. found another thing: shouldn't the android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" only be existent in the ListView itself?

Comment: I have tried individually everywhere actually did not work either 
:(

Comment: as far as i understand it, adding this to your parent layouts will block your childs (e.g. your listView from getting the focus/triggering the onClick). So the blockDescendants ONLY makes sense in the ListView. Assuming I correctly understand what you are doing

Comment: ok basically in this drawer layout I have a kind of overlay RelativeLayout (RL).
In This RL i have a button and onclick of this button the RL becomes invisible.
Untill the button click the RL is still active,during this any click in drawer doesnt work

Comment: okay, I think I misunderstood you: the click problem with the "drawer" you are talking about is about the whole Layout, not only the ListView?

Comment: drawer opens, in that the listview click doesnt work;
but the button on the RL works as it should

Comment: what's the layout for the listView items?

Comment: I'm only seeing the drawer itself, what I'm talking about is the "rows" of the ListView - which layout do they have?

Comment: i just realised i made an error while writing my comment above: the ListView should of course not block its descendants from getting focus, since then, the ItemClickListener would never be triggered - the Layout of a row in the list view should use blockDescendants so its containing elements (textViews etc.) don't get focused by the click.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83302/discussion-between-smaran-and-ruptha).